# How to queue http requests using node.js and zeromq

Tags: node.js, zeromq

our application server **Server-A** working all the time and sending data (if available) to other broker server **Server-B**. Here is an example:

```
//server-A.log
12 Mar 2015 18:28:20 - send data - http://server-b?user=dit&data=JSON_STRING 
12 Mar 2015 18:28:20 - send data - http://server-b?user=lea&data=JSON_STRING 
12 Mar 2015 18:28:20 - send data - http://server-b?user=alex&data=JSON_STRING 
12 Mar 2015 18:28:20 - send data - http://server-b?user=tom&data=JSON_STRING 
12 Mar 2015 18:28:20 - send data - http://server-b?user=luke&data=JSON_STRING 
12 Mar 2015 18:28:20 - send data - http://server-b?user=dit&data=JSON_STRING
```

Now I want to queue these request on the **Server-B** by using node.js and zeroMQ.

Here is my try... ZMQ queue:

```
// serverB-queue.js 
var zmq  = require('zmq'), 
    sock = zmq.socket('push');

sock.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
console.log('Queue bound to port 3000');

//PROBLEM TODO: WAIT FOR REQUEST FROM SERVER-A AND PUT DATA INTO THE QUEUE
```

Queue worker takes and process the incoming data

```
// serverB-queue-worker.js 
var zmq  = require('zmq'),
    sock = zmq.socket('pull');

    sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
    console.log('Worker connected to port 3000');

sock.on('message', function(data){
    // send data to user via websocket
});
```

So my question is, how can my serverB-queue.js listen for requests from server-A?

Comment: It looks like you're already sending requests from server A over HTTP (judging from your server-A.log), so you just need to build an HTTP listener in server B, which is the most common node.js tutorial out there.

Comment: @Jason ok so simple? I thought there is some ZMQ feature. thx.